# What is the best way to check all JSON properties values type?

Tags: json, spring, junit, jsonpath, assertj

I'm trying to check in my integration test if all of values from some specific property has the same type. I was trying to do it along with jsonPath and JsonPathResultMatchers but without success. Finally in I did something like this :

```
MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/weather/" + existingCity))
                 .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                 .andReturn();


String responseContent = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
TypeRef<List<Object>> typeRef = new TypeRef<List<Object>>() {
};

List<Object> humidities = JsonPath.using(configuration).parse(responseContent).read("$.*.humidity", typeRef);
Assertions.assertThat(humidities.stream().allMatch(humidity -> humidity instanceof Integer)).isTrue();
```

But I wonder if exist some clearer way to do this, can the same result be achieved with JSONPath ? Or AssertJ has some method to find it without usage stream code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personnaly would rather validate it against a  [JSON schema](http://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding). There are [Java validator implementations](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator) that could help you

Answer (score 4):

Just answering on the AssertJ part: `Stream` assertions are provided with some caveats as the `Stream` under test is converted to a `List` in order to be able to perform multiple assertions (otherwise you can't as a Stream can only be consumed once).

Javadoc: [`assertThat(BaseStream)`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/Assertions.html#assertThat-java.util.stream.BaseStream-)

Example:

```
assertThat(DoubleStream.of(1, 2, 3)).isNotNull()
                                    .contains(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
                                    .allMatch(Double::isFinite);
```

I have happily used https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit to check JSON, you can give it a try and see if you like it.